# parse xml using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

i am parsing Xml using ajax function in jquery in a jsp file

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sites.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {

    }
});
```

My problem is my xml file is not in the same path as my jsp file. The jsp path is `webProject/webcontent/temlates/store/SearchResult.jsp` and the xml path is `webProject/webcontent/WEB-INF/config/ampliflex.xml`.

What should my url be in the `$.ajax({` function?

Please Suggest

Comment: Use the absolute path to the file...

Comment: try this- ././WEB-INF/config/ampliflex.xml

Comment: Felix Kling :i am using it as url:"webProject/webcontent/WEB-INF/config/ampliflex.xml" but i am getting this error                 "Get http://localhost:7001/webProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/config/ampliflex.xml 404 Not Found" i used firebug to c the problem

Comment: @romi- have you tried my option

Comment: @Vivek: this is also not working, stiil showing the same error .

Comment: Is the WEB-INF directory even served by the web server?

Comment: @alnorth29 : yes it is in weblogics webcontent folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought that the WEB-INF directory would be private by default and so not accessible via an AJAX request. Try moving the XML file to some other part of your project.

Comment: yes when  i use some other xml file of some other path this is working. But the problem is i can not move ampliflex.xml from WEB-INF. is there any other way that i can parse it here.

Comment: @Romi I would think that you don't want to make the whole WEB-INF directory publicly visible. The file will be visible to servlets running on the server, so if you really can't move the file then you could create a servlet that loads the file and passes it on.

Comment: @ alnorth29: I tried this too. But can i use this servlet with in javascript tag ???

Comment: @Romi It should work fine, just do the AJAX request to the URL in the usual way. You'll want to set the response type for the servlet to text/xml or application/xml.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "webProject/webcontent/WEB-INF/config/ampliflex.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {

    }
});
```

Comment: @Romi do as other have suggested and move the xml then use the path as i've shown

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the file if you try accessing it directly with your browser (via localhost i mean)? if your ajax request can see the file so can your browser directly. i would suggest trying to find the correct url in your browser and use that in your ajax request.

Furthermore as mentionned above it is possible the WEB-INF directory is not accessible to client (hence my first question in this comment) so you can also try moving the xml file to a directory you know is accessible.

Comment: kyushiro: I used a xml file which is not accessible via browser but it is still parsable via ajax .